# Deploy for different environments from same manual job depending on commit message

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 10 environments. Each environment should have same manual jobs to deploy 5 services (5 buttons). The only difference between environemnt-1 jobs and environment-2 jobs are `tags`, `variables.only` check for commit message and `environment.name`.
E.g. I should be able to specify `[staging]` in commit message and have 5 separate buttons that deploy 5 services to staging. Same for `[production]`, etc...

```
staging-deploy-service1:
  <<: *deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  variables:
    ServiceName: service2
  tags:
    - dev-staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/

staging-deploy-service2:
  <<: *deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  variables:
    ServiceName = service2
  tags:
    - dev-staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/

staging-deploy-service3:
  <<: *deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  variables:
    ServiceName: service3
  tags:
    - dev-staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/

staging-deploy-service4:
  <<: *deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  variables:
    ServiceName: service4
  tags:
    - dev-staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/

staging-deploy-service5:
  <<: *deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  variables:
    ServiceName: service5
  tags:
    - dev-staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/
```

Currently I have to repeat this block for each environment - 10 times. So it's 50 jobs for just 5 services.

How can I simplify this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the perfect solution because having variable substitution in CI tags is still not [possible](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742) but if we forget the tags, using [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs) can do the trick :

```
.service_name:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SERVICE_NAME: ['service1', 'service2', 'service3', 'service4', 'service5']
        ENV: ['env1', 'env2', 'env3', 'env4', 'env5']

deploy_service:
  <<: *deploy
  <<: *service_name
  environment:
    name: $ENV
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_NAME
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $ENV'
      when: manual
```

If you really need to keep one tag per environment, you can still simplify your current config using one-dimensional matrix and using more anchors, ex for staging for all services :

```
.service_name: &service_name
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SERVICE_NAME: ['service1', 'service2', 'service3', 'service4', 'service5']

.staging_common: &staging_common
  environment:
    name: $staging
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[staging\]/'
      when: manual

.dev_staging_tags: &dev_staging_tags
  tags:
    - dev-staging

staging-deploy:
  <<: *deploy
  <<: *dev_staging_tags
  <<: *staging_common
  <<: *service_name
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_NAME
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your first example but instead of `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $ENV` I need to do something like `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[$ENV/]\ ` which doesn't work. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Also some environments have different commit message and env name e.g. `environment: name: production` and `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[prod\]/`. Is it possible to pass these two values as a single matrix element?